# Top 2 distinct in sql

Tags: sql

This is my test table in sql-server

the table structure is this

Table A

```
status   id    Col1    Col2      Col3      Date
A        111     Name1   Name4     Name6     2/18/14 5:54
B        111     Name1   Name5     Name6     3/18/14 5:54
B        111     Name2   Name6     Name6     5/12/14 5:54
B        111     Name2   Name6     Name7     10/11/13 3:34
```

required result:

```
status   id    Col1    Col2      Col3      Date
A        111     Name1   Name4     Name6     2/18/14 5:54
B        111     Name1   Name5     Name6     3/18/14 5:54
```

the answer has to be generic solution,as i don't know the RDBMS of my client :

I did this in sql-server :

```
select * 
  from (select *, 
               row_number() over(partition by status order by Date desc) as rn 
          from table
        ) 
 where rn=1
```

Any help is much appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select t1.* 
from table t1
join (select status, MAX(Date) as maxDate
      from table
      group by status) m
on m.status = t1.status and m.maxDate = t1.Date
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have only one maximum date per status, the following is probably the most efficient method of doing what you want:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.status = t.status and t2."date" > t."date");
```

For best performance, build an index on `table(status, "date")`.

This is saying:  "Get me all rows from the table where the `date` in the table has no larger value for that `id`".  That is a fancy way of saying, "get me the row for each `id` that has the maximum `date`."

Comment: thnaks a lot gordon.. the client is a retail/health/banking sector company currenltly using postgres but it works..

Answer (score 2):

This is a more generic solution (doesn't use functions like `row_number()`) but I believe there will be still differences in syntax as well problems with naming a column `Date` (quite likely a keyword/data type). Treat that as pseudo-sql.

```
select mytable.* from mytable
inner join
(
    select status, max(Date) Date
    from mytable
    group by status
) X
on X.status = mytable.status and X.Date = mytable.Date
```

There will be a difference in results if there's more than 1 record with the same maximum date for a status. The query in the question will return only 1 record, my query will return more than 1 in this case.